# How to prevent CSVPrinter from rewriting data again

Tags: java, list, csv

I'm using this method for writing data into csv but the problem is that it is rewriting data again below the old data. How can I prevent it from doing this ? I tried to set the  `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(answerFile, false);` but then its only writing the last array in the csv file.
I have this code:

```
public static void writeCsv(List<String> myList) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(answerFile, true);
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
    List<String[]> myListSplitted = myList.stream().map(row -> row.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    csvPrinter.printRecords(myListSplitted);
    csvPrinter.flush();
    csvPrinter.close();
}
```

This the method in which I'm calling this method:

```
    public static void appendAnswers() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(questionFile))) {
        String csvRow;
        int counter = 0;
        String[] csvArr;
        String data;
        br.readLine();
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((csvRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
            csvArr = csvRow.split(",");
            csvArr = Arrays.copyOf(csvArr, csvArr.length + 1);
            csvArr[csvArr.length - 1] = answers.get(counter);
            data = Arrays.toString(csvArr).replace("[", "").replace("]", 
            "").trim();
            counter++;
            myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split("\n")));
        }
        writeCsv(myList);

    }
```

Comment: `myListSplitted.stream().forEach(csvPrinter::printRecords)` give this a try?

Comment: Nope it's not working

Comment: Please show a minimal but complete example, including the input and the output, plus what you expect to happen.

Comment: Actually I've save csv rows in list and they are getting write fine. The problem is that its getting appended below the data again and again @tgdavies

Comment: You're explicitly opening the file in append mode, so any existing contents will be preserved.

Comment: I changed it but then it just write the last row leaving the other rows

Comment: I changed the FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(answerFile, false); but it just writes the last row

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html)  :

```
Prints values in a CSV format.

Values can be appended to the output by calling the print(Object) method.
```

Basically, `CSVPrinter` emulates a printer.  A printer appends new lines to whatever has already been printed.

If you want to overwrite, use `FileWriter` more directly rather than a printer emulator.